# Angular Binding to a @Attribute on a constructor

Tags: angular

I've a component test

**test.component.ts**

```
public getParameters() {
    return 'test.parameter';
}
```

**test.component.html**

```
<other-comp attr.data-target-panels="{{getParameters()}}">
</other-comp>
```

On this **other component** I've this constructor:

```
export class OtherComponent {

    constructor(@Attribute('data-target-panels') public targetPanels: string
    ) {

    }
}
```

How can i build this other-comp and binding the parameters value?

I try using

```
<other-comp attr.data-target-panels="{{getParameters()}}">
</other-comp>
```

and

```
<other-comp [attr.data-target-panels]="{{getParameters()}}">
</other-comp>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you use ```@Input ()```?

Comment: I'm using an existing component so it's not that easy to change this logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using some component in another component and binding value attribute binding with method, then method should be in the component where you are using component for example -

Component A -

```
<other-comp [datatargetpanels]="{{getParameters()}}">
</other-comp>

export class AComponent {

    constructor() {
    }
    public getParameters() {
       return 'Some data';
    } 
}
```

and In otherComponent you need to use `@Input` to get value like this -

```
export class otherComponent {
   @Input('datatargetpanels) 'datatargetpanels': string;
}
```

Comment: So, I need to use input here. But what's the "real" use of @Attributes? Use it when we've some static data?

Comment: @JMarques yes, Sorry but I am not fully sure about usage of `@attribute`, will update here once I study about it.

Comment: `@attribute` is for constant string literals only. You can't bind an object to it (normally because these aren't available when the constructor is running). You have to use `@Input()` and pick up the input in the `ngOnInit()` hook.